# Let $\Phi_n: \Bbb Z_n\to \Bbb Z_n$ s. t. $\Phi_n(x)=x^n+x^{n-1}+\ldots+x+1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

Let $\Phi_n: \Bbb Z_n\to\Bbb Z_n$ s. t. $\Phi_n(x)=x^n+x^{n-1}+\ldots+x+1$.
Could this function be surjective for some $n>2$? 
$\Bbb Z_n$ is the set of integers $\pmod n$.

Comment: A more interesting question seems to be: what is the size of the image of $\Phi_n$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$\phi(1) = n+1 = 1 = \phi(0)$$

But a surjective function between finite sets is bijective

Comment: so it's not surjective for $n\color{blue}=2$ either

Comment: I used that fact to show that $\exists x$ such that $\phi_n(x)=x \forall n>2$

Comment: @psidaga, that's a different question, right? Whether $\Phi_n$ has a fixed point. But as the answer above shows, $x=1$ is always a fixed point.